# how can i put the ScrollView on ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to put the Scrollview on the viewcontroller? is it possible? and i also want to put the UIView on the ScrollView.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView =[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 200)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 200);
    scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 200)];
    container.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:container];
```

In this code i tried to put the scrollview on the VC and also i tried to put View on the ScrollView.

```
            rb1 = [[RadioButton alloc] initWithGroupId:@"first group" index:j];
            rb1.frame = CGRectMake(20,dy,22,22);
            [container addSubview:rb1];
            [rb1 release];

            label1 =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, dy, 60, 20)];
            label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label1.text = [answers objectAtIndex:j];
            [container addSubview:label1];
```

and here i tried to put the a radio button on View.

I hope it is clear:) Sorry my bad english.Thanks.

Comment: See the answer below for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll occurs when the frame of a scroll view is less than your content size.

Your frame is having size (280,200) and you have provided same size to contentSize.

To make the scroll possible replace below line into your code.

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 260);

Answer (score 0):

Here you put the same content size as scroll size:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 200);
```

In content size you should enter the size of area you want to scroll. In your case scroll does not need to scroll because scrollable area is same as scrollView size.

Answer (score 0):

try this to put the scrollview on the controller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourClass : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

to put v/v try this

```
   NSUInteger scrollContentCount = 0;

   for (NSUInteger arrayIndex = 0; 
         arrayIndex < [contents count]; 
         arrayIndex++) {


    // set scorllview properties
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.mScrollView.frame.size.width * arrayIndex;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.mScrollView.frame.size;

    myScrollView.autoresizingMask = YES;

    // alloc - init PODetailsView Controller
    myController = [[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [myController.view setFrame:frame];

    // add view in scroll view
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:myController.view];

    scrollContentCount = scrollContentCount + 1;
}

 // set scroll content size
 self.myScrollView.contentSize = 
CGSizeMake(self.myScrollView.frame.size.width * scrollContentCount, 
                     self.myScrollView.frame.size.height);
  }
```